# using IP address connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code to connect to remote mysql from php application
I am using WAMP server where i installed my php application and on remote side also wamp server is there.

```
$con=mysql_connect('xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx','root','');
```

But connection is not being established.
Following warning is coming...

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (trying to connect via tcp://10:133)

Please any body give me some idea !
thanks !

Comment: What's the value of 'xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx'? Are you trying to use an IPv6 address?

Answer (score 3):

Should be dots not colons, like

```
$con=mysql_connect('xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx','root','');
//like
$con=mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dots in your IP address, not colons.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$con=mysql_connect('192.168.0.1','root','');
```

or if you want to specify the port:

```
$con=mysql_connect('192.168.0.1:3306','root','');
```

Comment: thanks a lot !Request is going. I had missed that one.                Now following warning is coming ...........                Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'rakesh-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:\wamp\www\jquery\jphp\jsontest.php on line 18

Comment: The problem is that the MySQL server doesn't allow access from all external sources (e.g. could be only a select few, or even no external sources at all).

Comment: try to read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367493/how-to-connect-to-mysql-on-host-on-another-computer-on-network

Comment: Your MySQL server is blocking your connection.